# How can I ensure that all data is synced across multiple devices using Delphi?

Tags: delphi

**how to make sure that all data is synced, and if specific types of dbs would be required for the syncing to work [using delphi]**

Hi all,

I am attempting to create a stock control system for a distribution centre,
I can figure out how to create the app in the sense of functionality and stuff.

But I am unsure of how to make sure that all data is synced, and if specific types of dbs would be required for the syncing to work. For instance, if it's downloaded on multiple devices (that may not be on the same network), how do I make sure that data entered on one device shows up on the other device? That both users see the information, after one of them updates a record, etc?

It's needs a shared server and to always be online, and further code to sync the data, I think. But I'm unsure of how to do that.

I tried googling and youtube videos but maybe I'm looking at it wrong, or not phrasing it correctly?

If you have a method, similar questions that have been answered, or any resources I could use to figure this out, please comment and/or share the links.

Thank you for taking the time to read my question.
xxx

Comment: How much coding have you done in your life?

Comment: a lot, roughly about 1400 lines of code in total.

Comment: In my life I have probably written 1 - 2 million lines of code in the last 30 years. In addition, I have developed and gone live with 20 or more pieces of software. Right now, there's a stock management system, I wrote, running a government warehouse. The value of the stock in there, is in the 100's of millions. It does what you outlined in your question.

Comment: A more simple answer to your question goes like this: That is the purpose of a database! All the data is written to- and read from- the database. That way all devices can see the same data.

Comment: @Lost-in-space That's not a lot, that's basically "Hello World Advanced"! ;-)

Comment: Based on the way OP has formed his question I'm guessing he is thinking about implementing some real time messaging system with which he would broadcast information about stock change to each connected device. And whole that is doable it is not necessary. All you need to do is recheck the available stock to see if you are able to finalize current order. And if you are smart you can temporarily reserve certain stock even before the order is finalized in order to prevent multiple users making order of the same stock items and thus accepting more orders that you have items in stock.

Comment: Based on the fact that he has admitted to writing a total of 1400 lines of code in his entire life, he has totally underestimated what it takes to become a career developer and also what it takes to make an application. That he doesn't understand the basic function of a database only adds support to my evaluation.

Comment: Sorry, I read that as 'how much of coding have you done in your file'. I've done IT in high school (based on my classwork alone I've done a lot more, not to mention the yearly projects as well )and I'm currently studying software engineering.  I apologise if I offended anyone but based on the fact that I'm barely 20 , I don't think I've underestimated what it takes to become a career developer, I was merely trying to challenge myself.

Comment: I understand how a database works I just was not sure how to prevent an error in the case where two people in different locations capture at the same time on the same live database and ensure that both ends see the same information without creating inconsistencies and anomalies. However I've managed to figure it out whilst trying to defend myself, so thank you for your constructive criticism. Arigatou!

Comment: You may want to obtain and read Cary Jensen's books on Delphi ClientDataSets and FireDac respectively. There are decent descriptions on resolving updates to datasets when using the briefcase model. Having said that, the problem you foresee, seldom occurs because 2 or more users are not updating the same data simultaneously. Think about your personal details at the bank. (This is now so far way from what SO is for!)

Comment: Thank you for the recommendations, much appreciated. The reason I thought of the problem, was because I was planning to create an automated PO number for each new purchase, which will then proceed to be the primary key used to refer to other data sets. Now if two people are capturing a new record at the same time, the system will(or would have) assigned the same PO number to both records. Assuming each record would require a minimum of 1 min for a person to capture all fields, the PO number would've not been 'booked' yet by on the database